# Struggling with language switcher for Craft 3

Tags: localization, craft3, multi-site

I am using SEOmatic helper class to get localizedUrls which is making life much easier! I would like to only display the localizedurl if the current entry is enable on that site. Below is what I have, has anyone successful done this for craft 3?

```
{% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}

{% set currentSiteLanguage = currentSite['language'] %}

{% set localizedUrlsArray = seomatic.helper.getLocalizedUrls() %}


{% for localizedUrls in localizedUrlsArray %}

{% if currentSiteLanguage != localizedUrls['language'] %}

    {% if entry is defined %}

        {% if entry.enabledForSite %}

            <a href="{{ localizedUrls['url'] }}"> {{ localizedUrls['language'] }}</a>

        {% endif %}


    {% else %}

        <a href="{{ localizedUrls['url'] }}"> {{ localizedUrls['language'] }}</a>

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this in detail in a bit, but something you can do is do a `{{ dump(localizedUrlsArray) }}` to look at the data that's being returned to you from `seomatic.helper.getLocalizedUrls()` to make sure it is what you think it is. Also you don't mention what is _wrong_ or not working as expected with the code you've shown?

Comment: I tried your code... it seemed to work fine here, it outputted a link to the entry in another localization in the same Site Group. What is not working as you're expecting it to?

Comment: @andrew.welch What I would like to happen is if you go to an english entry, but that entry is not set to live on another site/language then not show the link. My code it shows the link regardless. I am 100% positive I'm not using enabledForSite for site correctly.

Comment: Oh... maybe you want to check on the `.status` to make sure it's `live` then?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might finally have it working. If someone has a more elegant way to handle the index, tag and category I would love to see it!

```
        <!-- entry -->
        {% if entry is defined %}

            {% for siteForEntry in entry.getSupportedSites %}

                {% set site = craft.app.getSites.getSiteById(siteForEntry.siteId) %}

                {% if site.id != entry.siteId %}

                    {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(site).one() %}

                    {% if entryForOtherSite is not null %}

                        <li><a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ site.name }}</a></li>

                    {% endif %}

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        <!-- category -->
        {% elseif category is defined %}

            {% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}

            {% set sites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}

            {% for site in sites %}

                {% if site.id != currentSite.id %}

                    <li><a href="{{ site.baseUrl }}blog/category/{{craft.request.getLastSegment()}}">{{ site.name }}</a></li>

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        <!-- index and tags -->
        {% else %}

            {% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}

            {% set sites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}

            {% for site in sites %}

                {% if site.id != currentSite.id %}

                    <li><a href="{{ site.baseUrl }}{% for segment in craft.request.getSegments() %}{{segment}}/{% endfor %}">{{ site.name }}</a></li>

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Made a blogpost about a bit more flexible language switcher. You can find it here: https://www.thebasement.be/language-switcher-for-craft-3/